# What is the correct way to link the CSS/Javascript to webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to link the css and javascript files to my asp.net form.
I saw diffrent ways to do that. But dont know the diffrence.

1. **With `/`**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/animate.css">
   ```
2. **With `~/`**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/animate.css">
   ```
3. **With nothing**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/animate.css">
   ```
4. **With `../`**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/animate.css">
   ```

What is the correct way and what are the difference? Please explain also when to use what?

Comment: *"What is the correct way?"* - These variations affect what path is used to lookup the resource, but there isn't one "correct" way that applies in all situations.

Comment: `href` is path to the file. it will not be considers a variation since it will change based on location of file.

Comment: Hey why this question is vote for close? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that if you site is `http://example.com` and you have an application `http://exmaple.com/app1`.

1. This means root of the site. So it will become: `http://example.com/Content/animate.css`

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/animate.css">
   ```
2. The '~' means root of the application. so it will become: `http://example.com/app1/Content/animate.css`

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/animate.css">
   ```
3. This is realtive path so depending on where the file is, it will simply look for a Content folder in that same folder and then animate.css file. If you move the file where this is written to another folder, it will still look for a Content folder at that new location and then animate.css file.

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/animate.css">
   ```
4. This is saying go up one directory (from the file wherever this line of code is written) and then find Content folder and then animate.css file.

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/animate.css">
   ```

Each one has its place and use. Now that you know what they mean, you can choose which to use.

As a final note,

1. Write all the different ones in an html file.
2. Open Chrome debugger (or any browser debugger) and select the Network tab.
3. Access the html page form the browser
4. See how the browser interprets each path. You will see the browser making requests to each one using the complete URL.

You can use that technique anytime for any path to see what it gets resolved to.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is "2", because you start addressing from root of project

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/animate.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **With `/`**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/animate.css">
   ```

   This goes all the way to the root directory. If the file with that line is `example.com/folder/anotherFolder/index.html`, then that line of code will access `example.com/Content/animate.css`. It just goes to the very start.
2. **With `~/`**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/animate.css">
   ```

   This goes almost to the root like the first example, but stops one folder short. If the file with that line is `example.com/folder/anotherFolder/index.html`, then that line of code will access `example.com/folder/Content/animate.css`.
3. **With nothing**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/animate.css">
   ```

   I think for the most part, you will want this one. It accesses files relative to the current one. If the file with that line is `example.com/folder/anotherFolder/index.html`, then that line of code will access `example.com/folder/anotherFolder/Content/animate.css`.
4. **With `../`**

   ```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/animate.css">
   ```

   This one backs out just one folder/level. If the file with that line is `example.com/folder/anotherFolder/index.html`, then that line of code will access `example.com/folder/Content/animate.css`.

Answer (score -2):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/animate.css">
```

Use this when css file is inside a folder before `Content`